# virtualbox machine boots to efi shell

Tags: virtualbox, uefi

I recently transferred a virtualbox machine from my laptop to my recently reinstalled desktop. The image works fine on my laptop, but when I try to boot it on my new machine, I get dumped to an "EFI Shell" where it asks me about my hard drives rather than booting the machine. I want it to boot to the actual machine image rather than this shell. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It turns out that as I was messing around with getting the machine to load (due to Virtualization technologies being disabled), I clicked one too many items on the image settings page.

To fix this, go to the "Settings" page for the virtual machine, and click "System". Under the "motherboard" options, be sure that "Enable EFI (special OSes only)" is unchecked. Then click "OK", and try to boot the machine again. The option that was checked is basically how you get into the [EFI Interface](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#efi).

Comment: Sorry, was looking for a good link what EFI is. Must have found it then forgot to actually link it in the post.

Comment: and the sentence in the question.

Answer (score 8):

1. in Efi shell: `edit startup.nsh`
2. add line `FS0:\EFI\Path\To\Desired.efi`
3. Save, reboot.

Comment: Thanks! But why is this needed? Is the virtualbox EFI system not stored inside the image?