# VirtualBox Ubuntu guest from real partition image boots into emergency mode, can't get to login screen

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, uefi, systemd

I've got a dual boot system on my disk:

- Windows 10 64-bit: main OS
- Ubuntu 64-bit: secondary OS

I installed VirtualBox; I'm trying to use my real Linux partition as a Virtual Machine using Windows as the host. I've used the methods described [here](http://www.brool.com/post/virtualizing-an-ubuntu-partition-with-efi/).

Grub loads from the bootloader and allows me to select Ubuntu. I go through the loading screen, but never make it to the login page. Instead, it puts me into emergency mode on SystemD:

[image: Emergency mode systemd]

Looking into the logs, it seems that the VM is running a read-only system. How do I make the VM run a Read-write file system?

- Ubuntu works completely fine when booted on its own
- I have a CPU that supports 64-bit
- I have EFI booting on my computer and on VirtualBox, because they literally demand it
- I have virtualization on in BIOS, for sure (I've quadruple checked)

Comment: After reading the blog you posted, please post the output of `wmic diskdrive list brief /format:list` on Windows 10, and the output of `fdisk -l` from a Ubuntu LiveCD/USB.

Comment: `wmic diskdrive list` on Windows (partition 4): http://pastebin.com/SyKPSLaw
`fdisk -l` on my real Ubuntu partition (partition 6): http://pastebin.com/dbbCW843
Will do it from live Ubuntu as well, need to find my USB

Comment: What is the output of: `VBoxManage internalcommands listpartitions -rawdisk /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

Only your host OS, Windows 10, requires EFI.  You need to [disable EFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162148/virtualbox-machine-boots-to-efi-shell) on the VM.  Afterwards treat the virtual machine as if EFI didn't exist, and read [How to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142549/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-virtualbox).

Comment: See, the reason why I have EFI booting on is because now with the option unchecked I am getting "FATAL: INT18: BOOT FAILURE"

Comment: Recreate the virtual machine

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. My apologies if my post seemed vague, but I'm trying to virtualize an existing partition of Ubuntu.

Comment: You cant virtualize a mounted partition.  See [VirtualBox INT18 Boot Failure](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-936742-start-0.html) and replace CDROM with your partition,  For that matter I dont believe you can do what your attempting because the partition is not in the vmdk format.  A virtual machine actually virtualizes a file.

Answer (score 0):

I have exacly same problem [I followed these instructions](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-dual-boot-and-virtualize-the-same-partition-on-y-493223329) and I end up with same error. Solution which allow me to complete booting process was to

edit `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

and comment line with `/boot/efi` (by using `#`)